# Improve saving to CSV file (C#)

Tags: c#, csv, export-to-csv, stringbuilder, streamwriter

I'm writing column data to CSV file:

```
string sep = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator;
string csvFile = "MyName.csv";

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(csvFile))
{
    var newLine = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (int item in someTable)
    {
        string x = (string)dt.DataTable.Rows[item].Value("abc");
        newLine.Append(x);
        newLine.Append(sep);

        string x2 = (string)dt.DataTable.Rows[item].Value("abc2");
        newLine.Append(x2);
        newLine.Append(sep);

        string x3 = (string)dt.DataTable.Rows[item].Value("abc3");
        newLine.Append(x3);
        newLine.Append(sep);

        int x4 = (int)dt.DataTable.Rows[item].Value("abc4");
        newLine.Append(x4);
        newLine.Append(sep);

        //....and more data to Append - around 20
        ...
        writer.WriteLine(newLine);
        newLine.Clear();
    }
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();
}
```

It's possible to not easier and not always repeat `newLine.Append(sep);` ?
Or maybe other improvements?

Comment: You can use a library like CsvHelper to write the entire DataTable or any `List<T>` to a CSV directly. As for this code, you can save memory by writing to the StreamWriter directly. You can also loop over columns. There's no need for `Flush()` and `Close()`, these will be called automatically

Comment: Unfortunately, writing to a CSV can get quirky - if any of the fields contains separators or newlines, it will have to be quoted. Blindly formatting dates or numbers to strings can result in bad data or worse, incorrect dates. There's no way to tell what `4/7/2022` means but `2022-04-07` is the same everywhere

Comment: Agree with @PanagiotisKanavos. Just curious, where I can find the `Value()` function?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos are you able to put answer with CsvHelper ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential idea would be to create a variable to represent the row such as

`var row = dt.DataTable.Rows[item];`
and also create a list or array to hold all of the column names, something like

`string[] cols = {"abc", "abc2", "abc3"};` then inside of your current `foreach` loop you could do the following:

```
foreach (string colName in cols)
{
     newLine.Append((string)row.Value(colName));
     newLine.Append(sep);
}
writer.WriteLine(newLine);
newLine.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a library, [Sylvan.Data.Csv](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan) that makes this quite easy to accomplish. It handles the complexities of escaping delimiters and quotes, when necessary, which the naive implementations presented in other answers do not.

Here is an example implementation of an extension method using my library that would allow you to write `dataTable.SaveAsCsv("myfile.csv");`.

```
public static void SaveAsCsv(this DataTable dt, string filename)
{
  using var csvWriter = Sylvan.Data.Csv.CsvDataWriter.Create(filename);
  csvWriter.Write(dt.CreateDataReader());
}
```

My library is also the fastest CSV writer (and reader) for .NET, at least according to my [benchmarks](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Benchmarks/blob/main/docs/CsvWriterBenchmarks.md). It is even faster than the naive implementation.

Comment: I can't use use external library

Comment: Hilarious that you didn't mention that in your post.